# Passing a project to an sbt dynamic task

Tags: sbt

I have a sbt project that includes code generation.

Part of the build.sbt is

```
lazy val generator = (project in file("generator")).
   settings(mainClass := Some("com.example.Generator"))

lazy val generate = (project in file("generate")).
   dependsOn(generator).
   settings(runGeneration)

def runGeneration: SettingsDefinition = sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.taskDyn {
    val cachedFun = FileFunction.cached(
                streams.value.cacheDirectory / "generation"
            ) { (in: Set[File]) =>
                    val dir = (sourceManaged in Compile).value
                    (generator / run in Compile).toTask(" " + dir.getAbsolutePath).value
                    collectFiles(dir) 
                  }

        val dependentFiles = ((generator / fullClasspath in Compile) map { cp => cp.files }).taskValue.value

        val genFiles = cachedFun(dependenctFiles).toSeq
        Def.task {
            genFiles
        }
    }.taskValue
```

This seems to work and only generate files when a dependency has changed.  However, I expect to have multiple generators.  Rather than copy the code, I attempted to pass the `generator` project to it:

```
lazy val generate = (project in file("generate")).
   dependsOn(generator).
   settings(runGeneration(generator))

def runGeneration(p: project): SettingsDefinition = 
   <same as before but with p instead of generator>
```

This results in an error parsing the build file:

```
build.sbt:155: error: Illegal dynamic reference: File
        val dependentFiles = ((p / fullClasspath in Compile) map { cp => cp.files }).taskValue.value
                               ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

I am guessing the problem is that it cannot figure out at compile time if there is a dependency loop, so it convervatively gives an error.

Is there a way to get this to work?  Is there an entirely different construct that lets me know if running `generator` will produce a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that task definitions in `sbt` have two components, which look like they can be intermingled, but cannot.  If you write code like

```
Def.task {
  val doIt = checkIfShouldDoIt()

  if (doIt) {
    someTask.value
  } else { 
    ()
  }
}
```

this naively looks like it will only run `someTask` if `doIt` is true.  What actually happens is that `someTask.value` declares a dependency of this task on `someTask` and `someTask` is run before anything is done for this task.  To write the above code in a way that more directly maps to what actually happens, one would write

```
Def.task {
  val someTaskValue = someTask.value

  val doIt = checkIfShouldDoIt()
  if (doIt) {
    someTaskValue
  } else { 
    ()
  }
}
```

The attempt to run the task only when the dependencies had changed could not work in a single task.

My working solution does the following.  I modified the generator to take an additional argument and do nothing if that argument was false.  The two tasks were

```
// Task to check if we need to generate
def checkGeneration(p: Project) = Def.taskDyn {
  var needToGenerate = false
  val cachedFunction = FileFunction.cached(someDir) {
     (in: Set[File]) =>  
        needToGenerate = ! in.isEmpty
        Set()
    }

  val dependentFiles = ((p / fullClasspath in Compile) map { cp => cp.files }).taskValue

  Def.task {
    cachedFun(dependentFiles.value.toSet)
    needToGenerate
  }
}

// Task to run generation
def runGeneration(p: Project): SettingsDefinition = sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.taskDyn {
  val needToGenerate = checkGeneration(p).value

  Def.task {
    // Run generator as before but pass needToGenerate as additional argument
    ...
    // Used FileFunction.cached as before to find the generated files (but not run the generator)
    ...
  }
}
```

It is possible that I have more dynamic tasks than I need, but this works.